# Rails task naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I was wondering if there is a generally accepted naming convention in regards to rake tasks? My current naming convention starts with the object name(s), followed by the task being performed, so for a task that verifies user photos, the task name would be:

```
user:photos:verify
```

However, I can't help but think there might be a better way.